# Android TextView troubles

Tags: java, android, textview

Ok so i'm starting to learn Android and i cant append or set the text of the TextView.. i always get a NullPointerException.. anyone help me out?

Field variables

```
public TextView t = null;
public Button b = null;
```

My onCreate method

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dummy_button);

    //t.append("hello again");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
            HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                        // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                        // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                        // screen.
                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        controlsView
                                .animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                        // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                        // controls.
                        controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                        // Schedule a hide().
                        delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });
```

The listener i decided to put the append in..

```
contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("onClick", "before append");
            t.append("ummmm" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            Log.e("onClick", "after");
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the .xml file that i use in layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

<!--
     The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc.
-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:text="@string/dummy_content"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!--
     This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dummy_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="411dp"
        android:text="Why Hello There" />

</FrameLayout>
```

R.java.. it is auto generated however.. here is inside R.java

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int dummy_button=0x7f070002;
    public static final int fullscreen_content=0x7f070000;
    public static final int fullscreen_content_controls=0x7f070001;
    public static final int textView1=0x7f070003;
}
```

Any help would be amazing! :) i am quite new to Android development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OnCreate should be like this,

```
             @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                         setContentView(R.layout.xml);  

                         t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                         b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dummy_button);
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_id);`

Add it after `super.onCreate` and before you are finding any views.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forget to call `setContentView` method